# I want to use mobile through computer internet connection

Tags: networking

This is not that I have the computer use the mobile's connection but the opposite, I have a computer connected via VPN to an internal network where some services are exposed, I need to use one of those services in the mobile so what I want to do is to connect my mobile to my computer such a way that when I go to an internet address on the mobile that it uses the computers networking capabilities to send request, since computer connected to vpn the mobile request will of course be going through vpn, and I will be able to access one of the aforementioned services.

When I say mobile in this case I mean either an old IOS phone (IOS 5 I think) or an Android tabler, or perhaps even another computer connecting to the primary computer and tunneling all requests over it.

Comment: You can share a device's network connection with a mobile device, as described [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/use-your-pc-as-a-mobile-hotspot-c89b0fad-72d5-41e8-f7ea-406ad9036b85#:~:text=Select%20the%20Start%20button%2C%20then,Internet%20connection%20with%20other%20devices), for example. For a more specific answer, you'd do well to be more specific in the formulation of your question.

Comment: Connecting PC and mobile while connected to a VPN on the PC will fail if the VPN software disallows local network connection (for security reasons otherwise your PC would be a bridge between the an outer network and the protected inner network).

Comment: macOS, Windows, and Linux all have "Internet Sharing" or "Internet Connection Sharing" features that make your computer act as a wireless router. But you probably need to make sure your computer's main network connection is via Ethernet, not Wi-Fi, so you can put the Wi-Fi interface into AP mode.

Comment: see if it's helpful tot you: https://www.lifewire.com/reverse-tether-share-laptop-internet-connection-with-phone-2377917